# how to first write and then read a text file in python

Tags: python, input, file-io, output

This doesn't work:

```
with open("c.txt","r+") as f: 
    f.write("Happy Birthday\n")
    print(f.read())
```

But this does:

```
with open("c.txt","r+") as f:
    print(f.read())
    f.write("Happy Birthday\n")
```

Is there any mode like `a+`, `r+` to make upper code work. I have tried both of them in my upper code but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to close a file before writes are actually committed to the file

Comment: Please don't abuse blockquotes for emphasis. Spend a bit of time with https://stackoverflow.com/markdown to learn how to use Markdown.

Comment: the issue that the first code does not give any output is the pointer of the current file position. after writing to a file, the position points to the end of the file. 
we can use f.seek(0) to set the position pointer to the start of the file.then reading from the file will work.